# Es posible tener dos proyectos con el mismo nombre de paquete?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Mi idea es poder usar el mismo archivo de Google.services.json para dos proyectos distintos, ya que tengo un límite de 3 proyectos en firebase y ya tengo usado el máximo. Quiero poder usar el mismo archivo json para dos apps que usan la misma database. De que forma podría hacerlo?, si pongo el mismo nombre del paquete a las dos apps funcionara?.

Espero puedan ayudarme, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

**El nombre de paquete (id de aplicación ) de una aplicación debe ser único y no puede repetirse entre aplicaciones que son subidas a Google Play**,

Puedes usar un nombre repetido en pruebas pero no podrás subir esta aplicación a la tienda  Google Play.

Recuerda que el archivo **google-services.json** tiene referencias a el nombre de paquete  (id de aplicación)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Con respecto a tus preguntas:

> Mi idea es poder usar el mismo archivo de Google.services.json para
>   dos proyectos distintos.

Puedes usar el mismo `google-services.json`  pero el id de aplicación no debe repetirse en la Google Play Store.

> ya que tengo un límite de 3 proyectos en firebase y ya tengo usado el
>   máximo.

Puedes usar un solo proyecto `Firebase` para tus proyectos para eso precisamente se usa el nombre de paquete para diferenciar una aplicación de otra, **No es necesario crear un proyecto `Firebase` por aplicación.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Quiero poder usar el mismo archivo json para dos apps que usan la
>   misma database. De que forma podría hacerlo?, si pongo el mismo nombre
>   del paquete a las dos apps funcionara?.

Puedes usar el mismo archivo google-services.json pero en realidad deseas usar el mismo nombre de paquete, si deseas esto en realidad estarías indicando la misma aplicación y no una aplicación diferente.

Answer (score -1):

Si se puede, de hecho, yo lo utilizo en algunos proyectos.

Por ejemplo, tengo una app que es una app administrativa donte creo contenido para otra app, y al mismo tiempo las dos estan conectadas, por lo que puedo administrar y ver contenido con una que la otra genera.

Para enlazar dos proyectos a una misma cuenta de Firebase podes hacer lo siguiente dentro de Android Studio

Tanto en el primer como segundo proyecto , podes conectarlo siguiendo estos pasos

### Desde Android Studio

1.- Entra a tools - Firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Selecciona cualquiera de los servicios y clica el boton conectar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- Selecciona el proyecto donde queres conectar la app que estas trabajando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta ventana te puede saltar una vez si fallo al apretar conectar, o te sale otra ventana en la cual seleccionas un proyecto existente y le das continuar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No encontre la imagen donde me salia esta ventana, pero si no te sale la imagen de arriba, seguramente te salga esta antes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi es donde seleccionas choose an existing project y enlazas ese proyecto con un proyecto ya hecho de Firebase. Como podes ver, en la opcion de choose an existing project nos dice al lado la cantidad de apps enlazadas que tiene ese proyecto.

Una vez conectado, todo deberia estar bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Desde Firebase

1.- Configurar proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Añadir SHA-1 de tu nueva app (apretando add fingerprint)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma enlazamos mas de una app a una misma base de datos

Recuerda, lo mas importante es que añadas el SHA-1 del nuevo proyecto a la configuracion de Firebase. Si lo haces desde Android Studio se pone solo, si lo haces desde la web tenes que añadir el SHA-1 del nuevo proyecto.

Actualizacion

Como te podes fijar en esta foto, tengo 2 proyectos distintos conectados a una misma database de Firebase, con distintos nombres de paquete

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es necesario que los dos tengan el mismo nombre del paquete?

Comment: No, no es necesario, ahi te actualizo con una foto

Comment: De esta manera puedo tener una sola app de Android en firebase y las demás podrán trabajar con la database sin registrarlas en firebase?

Comment: Tenes que registrar los proyectos en Firebase que van a usar la Database, de lo contrario no te va a funcionar nada, la authenticacion es muy importante que tenga el SHA-1 del proyecto enlazado en cuestion para poder funcionar

Comment: Hacelo desde Android Studio a la conexion para ahorrarte tener que bajarte el google-services.json y configurar un nuevo proyecto dentro de otro

Comment: Sino en Firebase en la imagen de configuracion apretas Agregar App y configuras una app nueva para ese proyecto con tu otro paquete, de esa forma se va a ver como la ultima foto, dos proyectos, dos paquetes distintos, pero conectados al a misma base de datos

Comment: El problema que tengo es que tengo 4 apps que usan la misma database. Sin embargo, alcanzo a registrar un máximo de 3 en firebase. Tres de estas apps son de Android y la cuarta es de IOS, por eso quiero tratar de ingresar dos apps de Android en una para poder quedar con 2 de android y 1 de ios. No sé si se entiende jajaja. Saludos y gracias por tu tiempo.